# Should this phrase be put at the end of a paragraph or at the start of a new one?

Tags: phrases, paragraphs

The phrase is 'now onto the science.'

**Context**:

We first set up the bunsen burner and locate an appropriate flask. We then wear our goggles. *Now, onto the science.*

*Now, onto the science.* We expect that the rate of change of the effect of the catalyst to be blah blah...

Where should the phrase 'Now, onto the science' be put?

Comment: There is no right answer or even an established framework for selecting a preferred answer. It's a matter of taste and style. Use what appeals best to you.

Comment: No; the phrase is 'now, on to the science'. And discourse grammar (eg arrangement of sentences) almost certainly belongs on Writers SE (though I'd not place _Now, on to the science._ at the end of a paragraph very often).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially a request for writing advice and would necessarily attract primarily opinion-based answers, both of which are grounds for closing the question as off-topic at this site.

Answer (score 0):

The placement of *now, on to the science* depends on how you or the character you are writing about would say the words aloud.

Many years ago, I worked as a lab teaching assistant in a large university.  If I gave a safety-related instruction such as "we need to put on our goggles for the next step", I would pause and wait until everyone was ready.  In this case you want *now, on to the science* at the start of the second paragraph.

On the other hand, if I was simply describing the lab work in a tutorial where (obviously) goggles weren't needed, I might summarize the steps casually and finish with  "and if we're all good with that, let's take a look at the science..."  Then I would pause before I began talking about the main topic of the tutorial.

And one final thought: If you are writing a lab manual and want to sound casual in tone, read it aloud and see where the pauses fall naturally.  That's where you should break the paragraphs.